# Asymptotic Notation - Linear Search

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Among, Big-O, Big-Omega and Big-Theta, Indicate the efficiency class of a linear search.

The best case (Big-O) for a linear search would be, 1 (or *constant*) because the item being looked for, could be the first in the list.

The worst case (Big-Omega) for a linear search would be, n (or *linear*) because it could be the last item in the list of n items.

**However, what would the efficiency class of Big-Theta (average case) be for a linear search?**

Comment: It is a common misconception that $O$, $\Omega$ and $\Theta$ correspond to the best-case, worst-case and average-case. They are upper-bound, lower-bound and bilateral bounds of some complexity function.

Answer (score 0):

The average case estimate depends on the statistical distribution of the data, so is not uniquely defined.

In the uniform case (all elements equally likely to be a match, and probability of a match being $p$),

- with probability $p$ you perform between $1$ and $n$ comparisons (equally weighted),
- with probability $1-p$ you perform $n$ comparisons.

In total,

$$p\frac{n+1}2+(1-p)n=\left(1-\frac p2\right)n+\frac p2$$

which is $\Theta(n)$.